# Samsung T5 cannot be accessed in macOS guest running on VirtualBox macOS host

Tags: virtualbox

I am running the latest version of VirtualBox with the extension pack (version 6.1.8). Guest additions (version 6.1.8) is installed on the macOS guest using the `spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963` patch.

The Samsung T5 is APFS-formatted and assigned (✓) to the guest using the Devices/USB menu.

Running `diskutil list` on the host doesn’t list the Samsung T5, same on the guest.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT: I am able to access a Samsung BAR APFS-formatted flash drive so the issue appears to be specific to the Samsung T5**

Comment: Can you post text or an image showing the differences?

Comment: @DavidAnderson When I assign the Samsung BAR to the guest, it immediately shows up in Finder. What would you like to see?

Comment: @sunknudsen Is the drive not mounting but still showing up? If so, try First Aid. Do you have the Extension Pack installed? That is necessary for reading USB drives in VirtualBox. You can also try HFS as APFS does have some issues reading in VirtualBox.

Comment: Is the drive encrypted?  If so, then that might be the issue.  I haven’t tried with VirtualBox, but with VMWare Fusion, I occasionally have issues where the password prompt doesn’t display when I attempt to mount the drive.

Comment: @Todd Extension pack installed but thanks for suggesting

Comment: @user128998 The drive is encrypted, but it doesn’t show at all in Disk Utility so I believe it’s not a mounting issue.